# Why are my creepers not spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a creeper farm recently (illmango's design). On his video, the creepers were spawning pretty frequently, but I don't get as many spawns. (I get some spawns, just not the ratio I was hoping for.) Is this because I'm on an online server? (5-20 players online most of the time) or is there any other problem?

[image]

Comment: Oh, and im on 1.12.2 BTW

Comment: That should be in the question.

Comment: 1. Yes, having many players online can reduce the mob rate, because even though the mobcap grows with a higher number of players, it's still taken up a lot faster. 2. Also, is the server render distance below 10? The wiki says that that can reduce spawning rates. 3. Have you tried building the same design in Singleplayer?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, I did build it in a singleplayer world before i built it on the multiplayer server. The spawn rates were much higher on the singleplayer world. I actually think its cuz of the players online, it looks like i get more spawns when its less crowdy on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Spawn rates are dispersed among all players that are currently logged in to the server. If you keep an eye on your farm, you will notice a vast difference between when there is 5 players online, and 20.

For each player that is currently online, there is a valid spawning area around each player.

[image]

As an example, let's say the mob cap is 100. If there is 5 players online, then that means ~20 mobs will be spawning near each player, including you at each interval. If there are 20 players online, that will drop to ~5.

Depending on where each player is can affect whether or not mobs can spawn, for example if a player is in the nether, or in a well lit area, this reduces the amount of mobs that can spawn near that player, which can increase your farm's spawn rates. If a player is in a cave, or out in the wilderness during nighttime, mobs will be able to spawn around them, reducing your farm's spawn rates.

Comment: The mobcap grows with the number of players. I don't know how exactly, but it's something roughly on the order of `100+(20*players)`, I think. I think OP's main problem is that he expects the farm to work great from a usual AFK spot, but other players are just regularly on the surface/caves/etc.

Comment: Let's add the spawn cap mechanics are quite wonky. I've watched quite a few videos of group playthroughs and one player or pair of players would get swarmed by crowds of mobs while the others traveled a world devoid of life... until the game suddenly changed its mind and reversed the situation.